# Save image to disk on a button click in a Web page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have some images in my Asp.net web page. My requirement is to save a selected image to users disk while clicking a save button.Normally all browser has the provision for right click save as option.But I have to implement this feature on an html input button click. I have the following questions.

1. How can I make a script to do this functionality which should work on all major browsers
2. Do we get any jQuery library which does this functionality
3. Can I get any alternative in asp.net technology rather than java script/jQuery for doing the same functioanlity

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: http://instructions.wikihow.com/Create-a-Download-Button

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a client-side javascript library. It is not involved with serving files to download.

You can provide a download on any button click in asp.net. jQuery is not required for downloading files.

Your code in the event handler would look as follows:

```
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));
    Response.WriteFile(filePath + fileName);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
```

Comment: I don't want the download functionality. I mean when I click on html button it should open save as dialog with necessary filtering options for an image

Comment: This will open the open / save as dialog box. Filtering is provided by the `ContentType`. Set it as per your document type.

Comment: No, It will show download dialog and download the images in Downloads folder. I want the same as that of the context menu save image as functionality

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write a file straight to disk from a website, period. That's just sensible security. A regular download link/button will always invoke the standard download process of the browser, in which you have no say whether the file will be saved at all or where to. The only way to circumvent that is to create a native browser plugin which the user will have to install first, which will write files from your site straight to a specific location on disk. Please be extremly careful writing such a plugin should you do so so it does not become a gaping security hole for everybody.